# Android: Xamarin JNI Binding -- Abstract Class inheritance

Tags: android, java-native-interface, xamarin

I'm running into roadblocks with Xamarin JNI bindings when trying to bind with a open source graphing project (https://github.com/pardom/AndroidUtils)

The project has the following Abstract class:

```java
public static abstract class AbstractPoint implements Comparable<AbstractPoint> {
  ....
  @Override
    public int compareTo(AbstractPoint another) {
        return Double.compare(mX, another.mX);
    }
}
```

The static class(LinearPoint) that inherits AbstractPoint does not implement the above compareTo() method

I'm getting the following binding error:

'Com.Michaelpardo.Android.Widget.Chartview.LinearSeries.LinearPoint' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Com.Michaelpardo.Android.Widget.Chartview.AbstractSeries.AbstractPoint.CompareTo(Java.Lang.Object)'

Can anyone advise?

Thanks